# Eval return value

Tags: perl, eval, return-value

Is it correct code?

```
my $ttt = eval {
 my @a=(1,2);
 return \@a;
};

print @$ttt[1]. "\n";
```

I thought that an eval block is evaluated on the fly and does not exist after execution. Are there any minuses in that decision?

Comment: What's the question?  What are you expecting and what happened that didn't match your expectation.

Comment: eval block is compiling and running on fly, I am afraid than array will be destroyed by garbage collector

Comment: It is **not** compiling and running on the fly.  That is very incorrect.  This is the form of `eval` that is pronounced `[traɪ]`.  And garbage collection will only kick in when refcount hits zero.

Comment: ah, no it won't be destroyed so long as a reference still exists.  And if your code is in a loop or a subroutine and is executed a second time, `my @a` will be allocated a new array not associated with the one previously returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The eval block remains part of the code in memory.  Is that what you are trying to avoid?  If so, this isn't the right way to do it and you should explain more the underlying problem you are trying to solve.

The code will run, but you are using an array slice in the print where you probably intend to use a simple array dereference:

```
print $$ttt[1]. "\n";
```

You also aren't checking to see if the eval succeeded; the following proceeds to the print and then (if you have warnings enabled) gives a Use of uninitialized value warning:

```
my $ttt = eval {
    die "horribly";
    my @a=(1,2);
    return \@a;
};

print @$ttt[1]. "\n";
```

Answer (score 3):

The eval block is parsed with the rest of the code and its return value is a reference to the array `@a`. That reference is assigned to `$ttt`. While the eval block goes out of scope, `@a` still has a non-zero reference count (thanks to `$ttt`) so it still exists.

Answer (score 3):

Your use of `eval` is useless and you don't check the result, but I have a feeling what you're trying to grasp has really nothing to do with `eval`, but when variables are freed.

Perl uses reference counting to know when it's safe to free a variable. A variable is freed as soon as nothing references it. In addition to references, lexical (`my`) variables are also referenced by the scope in which they are created, and package variables are also referenced by the package in which they reside.

Under "normal" circumstances, a variable will be destroyed on scope exit as the only reference to it gets removed*. Scopes are created by many things including the curlies of subs and `eval`. Here's an example:

```
use feature qw( say );

{ package D; DESTROY { say "Destroyed $_[0]"; } }

{
    my $x = bless({}, 'D');   # $x's refcnt is 1.
    say "Before scope exit";
}                             # $x's refcnt drops to 0, so it's freed.
say "After scope exit";
```

Output:

```
Before scope exit
Destroyed D=HASH(0x8eff768)
After scope exit
```

Now, what if you stored a reference to `$x` outside of the scope in which `$x` resides?

```
use feature qw( say );

{ package D; DESTROY { say "Destroyed $_[0]"; } }

my $ref;
{
    my $x = bless({}, 'D');   # $x's refcnt is 1.
    $ref = \$x;               # $x's refcnt is 2.
    say "Before scope exit";
}                             # $x's refcnt drops to 1, so it's not freed.
say "After scope exit";
$ref = undef;                 # $x's refcnt drops to 0, so it's freed.
say "After clearing reference";
```

Output:

```
Before scope exit
After scope exit
Destroyed D=HASH(0x8cc4768)
After clearing reference
```

In your code, the returned reference to `@a` keeps `@a` alive even after the scope that created it is exited. This can be verified by printing `$ttt`, and then `@$ttt`.

```
ARRAY(0x99464b8)
1 2
```

If you were to enter the block multiple times, you get references to different variables because `my` allocates a new variable each time*. Compare

```
my @a;
for (1..2) {
    my $x = $_;
    push @a, \$x;
}
say $a[0];  # 1
```

with

```
my @a;
my $x;
for (1..2) {
    $x = $_;
    push @a, \$x;
}
say $a[0];  # 2
```

* — Implementation varies from this explanation, but it's an optimisation that's not suppose to have visible side-effects.